# Grails: check if a specific property has an error

Tags: grails

Im currently working on grails constraints. I have class that looks like this

```
@Validateable
class StudentBean{
   def String name;
   def String age;
   def String address;

   def List<ErrorBean> errors = [];
   static constraints = {
       age nullable : false, validator : { val, obj, errors->
           if(val<10)
               errors.rejectValue("age", "student.age.notQualified.message", [val] as Object[], "Student not qualified."); 
       } 
   }
}
```

Now, assuming I declared a lot of constraints and then I call student.validate()

How will I know if a specific property has an error? Example, I just want to know if "age" property has an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that your object has errors by checking `student.validate()`, you can use:

```
student.errors.getFieldError( "age" )
```

Remember that you can also [validate only custom properties](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html):

```
student.validate(["age"])
```